# TeamCity Build Erroring Out while doing Git Push

Tags: gitlab, teamcity, gitlab-ci-runner, teamcity-8.0

I have teamcity build steps which is based on command line. My objective is, I want to upload code into gitlab using the git commands from team city build steps
Below are my commands :

```
git config --global user.name "username"

git config --global user.email "username@gmail.com"

git init
ssh -T git@gitlab.com

git checkout -b new_code7
```

below curl download file

```
curl -u %OIC_USERNAME%:%OIC_USERPASSWORD_TEST% \
    -H "Content-Type:octet-stream"  -X GET -o newintegration.iar \
    %OIC_TEST_INSTANCE%/ic/api/integration/v1/integrations/BX_AR_RECEIPTS_INBOUND_INT%7C01.00.0001/archive

git add .

git commit -m "adding code to master2" 

git push origin new_code7
```

After build is executed I am receiving following error

```
    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  100    11  100    11    0     0     25      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    25
  /mnt/agent/work/48738e7d1b6529be/src
  100    11  100    11    0     0     25      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    25

  newintegration.iar

  On branch new_code7

  nothing to commit, working tree clean

  Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,172.65.251.78' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

  git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights

  and the repository exists.

  Process exited with code 128
```

Comment: Manual git operations require explicit manual authorization. No matter, login+password or ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have the correct ssh key in your machine.